# How can address this python plotly.express error: "Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed"

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I faced a problem in python and was wondering if someone is able to help me solve it.

I get below error when I try to use the the "show()" function for “plotly.express” library.

> ValueError: Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not
> installed

I tried below 2 methods to solve, it still does not work. They are the recommended solutions by many sources online.

```
1 - pip install ipykernel 
2 - pip install --upgrade nbformat
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thank you,

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = pd.read_csv('daimond_data.csv')
data = data.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)

fig = px.scatter(data_frame=data, x='carat', y='price', size='depth',color='cut', trendline='ols' )

print(fig.show())
```

Comment: Did you restart your kernel after these commands?

Comment: Yes, but it is not fixed. I am using Jupyter in VSC.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I uninstalled the `nbformat` package from the global and the user environment, then reinstalled it on the local environment.